# Are there Fingerprint Readers that Can Connect to my Macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro

I'm building an app that requires fingerprint scanning. However, I've noticed most fingerprint scanners out there only connect to Windows Devices. Is there a way to get a fingerprint scanner connected to my Macbook? I only need to get the picture of the fingerprint.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your laptop does not come with Touch ID.  The only 3rd party unit I know of is the Eikon To Go USB Fingerprint Reader. Made to work on Macs.  You can find it [here](https://smile.amazon.com/Eikon-Go-USB-Fingerprint-Reader/dp/B001EHHWNG), and [here](https://www.neurotechnology.com/fingerprint-scanner-upek-eikon-to-go.html). This unit is described on many other web sites. Just Google it to see other sites. I think this unit is out of production but Amazon advertises the reader.  I'd check to make sure its compatible with your system software.

Do you own a regular scanner? Since you only need a print of your fingerprint, have you thought of scanning your finger by holding it down on scanner screen and scanning it?

Comment: My laptop comes with touch ID, I'm wondering if there's a way I can access the fingerprints in touchID or even the algorithm, as I wanted to vectorize the fingerprint into a string, then write custom similarity checks against a reliable source of input of fingerprints. ex) Allow Doritos dusted fingerprints to pass